# No item named 'timestamp' for DataFrame while there is really one

Tags: python, pandas

I have extracted the table below from a csv file :

```
date                 user_id  whole_cost  cost1             
02/10/2012 00:00:00        1       1790      12         
07/10/2012 00:00:00        1        364      15         
30/01/2013 00:00:00        1        280      10         
02/02/2013 00:00:00        1        259      24         
05/03/2013 00:00:00        1        201      39         
02/10/2012 00:00:00        3        623       1          
07/12/2012 00:00:00        3         90       0          
30/01/2013 00:00:00        3        312      90         
02/02/2013 00:00:00        5        359      45         
05/03/2013 00:00:00        5        301      34         
02/02/2013 00:00:00        5        359       1          
05/03/2013 00:00:00        5        801      12
```

For this purpose I used the following statement :

```
import pandas as pd

newnames = ['date','user_id', 'whole_cost', 'cost1']
df = pd.read_csv('expenses.csv', names = newnames, index_col = 'timestamp')

pivoted = df.pivot('timestamp','user_id')
```

But this last line generate the error message : `no item named timestamp`.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: replace `timestamp` with `date` .

Comment: Thanks.I had equally forgot to remove the header from the spreadsheet but it is resolved now.

Comment: You don't need to modify csv . make change in your code.

Comment: In fact it still not working with index_col = 'date' for an unknown reason. The following statement works fine : df = pd.read_csv('expenses.csv', header=False, names = newnames)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like column name `timestamp` is not present in the dataframe.
Try `index_col = 'date'` instead of `index_col = 'timestamp'` also use `pares_dates = ['date']` while using `pd.read_csv`.

This should work:
`df = pd.read_csv('expenses.csv', header = False, names = newnames, index_col = 'date', parse_dates = ['date'])`

Hope this helps.

Comment: In fact I had to remove it else I will have an error message when doing pivoted = df.pivot('date','user_id') : apparently 'date' will not be recognized having a name if I use it as an index ( by doing index_col = 'date').